# Subquery returns more than one row - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to fetch the No.of Count in each city with Ascending order. But I get the error as subquery returns more than one row.

Eg: One Table contains all the city,state and pincode. In another table we would have list of user records with their corresponding city. So I've tried to take the No.of users in each city with its count.

EG: Table A

```
City State Pincode
ABC  TN    600001
ABD  TN    600001
ABE  KA    500001
ABF  KA    500002
ABG  KA    500003
CDE  KL    500004
CDF  KL    500004
```

Table B

```
Userid Answer
1      ABC
2      ABC
3      ABD
4      ABD
5      ABD
6      ABD
7      ABE
8      ABE
9      ABD
10     ABC
```

Sql Query:

```
SELECT count(a.answer) from table b as a where a.answer=(select distinct(b.city) from table a as b);
```

So I'm getting subquery returns more than one row. Anybody help me to resolve this and would be much helpful to learn SQL Query.

Comment: Change your `=` to `IN` so that you get where the answers are in that sub-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select count(*) as cityCount, answer 
from B inner join A on B.answer = A.city group by answer
```

Comment: Thanks naveen goyal :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't understand how to use the `AS` keyword: it's to make alias, what you don't need here.

You're looking for the `GROUP BY` statement

If you want all city information + the number of answer by city, you can do this:

```
SELECT count(b.Answer) as count_answer, City, State, Pincode 
FROM table b join a on a.City=b.Answer 
GROUP BY City
```

see mysql documentation for more on this ;)